# Is it possible to install a newer version of kernel32.dll into win 7 x64 that includes the function GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime?

Tags: windows-7, kernel32

Sorry for the noob question,folks. My new version of Vectorworks CAD 2022 won't run on my Win 7 x64 due to a missing procedure entry point. My laptop is too old to upgrade to Win 10 and I was hoping for a workaround, besides buying a new laptop. I tried downloading and installing a new kernel32.dll (probably for Win 10) that included the needed function but Windows 7 would not start up afterwards. Are my only options to (1) stay with the older version of Vectorworks or (2) buy a new computer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime problem by using Vxkex https://github.com/vxiiduu/VxKex

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: @starball no i m not affiliated with them!